# Tailwind CSS - Switch color theme between "light", "dark" or "system settings"

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-8, tailwind-css

Tailwind CSS provides two different ways to enable dark mode on your website.

The first way is through media, which means if your OS supports dark mode and it's activated. Your website will be automatically displayed in dark mode.

My `tailwind.config.js`:

```json
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'media',
};
```

The second way is through "class", meaning if your `<html>` tag has the `class="dark"` assigned. Your website will be displayed in dark mode.

My `tailwind.config.js`:

```json
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
};
```

Is there a simple way of using both of these options at once?

The effect I want to achieve is that the user can set their preference between "light", "dark" and "system settings".

Similar to the function that is used here on Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow theme settings]

If this option is not currently possible with Tailwind CSS, what would be the cleanest and simplest workaround?

**Information about my project:**

- Tailwind CSS
- Laravel 8
- Fortify
- Jetstream
- Livewire

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same use case in my project. I solved it by using the class mode together with a media watcher. You need to set the class on page load and on a change of the settings and also when the event fires.

```
const setTheme = (isDark) => {
  document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
  if (isDark) {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
  }
};

if (settingIsAuto) {
  setTheme(window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches);
}

window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', e => {
  const newIsDark = e.matches;
  if (settingIsAuto) {
    setTheme(newIsDark);
  }
});

// watch for settings changes
```

Comment: Thanks man!
Had to modify it just slightly because TailwindCSS now wants the 'dark' class inside the <html> tag and not in the <body> tag... 
Maybe that changed some time?

Comment: I just changed the "document.body.classList.remove('dark');" and "document.body.classList.add('dark');" to "document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');" and "document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');"

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was a mistake. Thanks for fixing it!